# How to load two collect emitted values from two different flows?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

New to Android Development (2 months)

have a problem with emitting and collecting data. kinda hart to understand what's going on.

The problem is that, now i am getting a request token which i need to get session ID after logging in.

How can i store this token and then how can i use it in another flow which gives me session id?

Thanks!

i have this in **ViewModel.kt**

```
class LoginViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

val apiKey = "acdbc7ef61877f0d6b3e29d062218ccc"

private val _loginState = MutableSharedFlow<Resource<TokenResponse>>()
val loginState = _loginState.asSharedFlow()


fun getActualKey(apiKey: String){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        loginResponse(apiKey).collect{
            _loginState.emit(it)
        }
    }
}

fun loginResponse(apiKey: String) = flow {
    val response = RetrofitHelper.tokenService.getRequestToken(apiKey)
    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        val body = response.body()
        Resource.Success(body).let {
            emit(Resource.Success(body!!))
        }
    } else {
        val error = response.errorBody()?.string()
        emit(Resource.Error(error.toString()))
    }
}
```

}

and this in **Fragment** where i collect.

```
class LoginFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentLoginBinding>(FragmentLoginBinding::inflate) {

private val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel by viewModels()

val apiKey = "acdbc7ef61877f0d6b3e29d062218ccc"

override fun viewCreated() {
    observe()
}
override fun listeners() {
    binding.btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            loginViewModel.loginState.collectLatest {
                loginViewModel.getActualKey(apiKey)
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun observe() {
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            loginViewModel.loginState.collectLatest {
                when (it) {
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        Log.d("tag", "cool ${it.data.requestToken}")
                    }

                    is Resource.Error -> {
                        Log.d("tag", "error")
                    }

                    is Resource.Loading -> {
                        Log.d("tag", "loading")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why use flows instead of simple suspend functions? Flows that emit only one value just complicate everything. The major benefit of coroutines is that you can use simple sequential code even if it's asynchronous behind the scenes

Comment: Also, don't you have a cyclic dependency here? It seems you're collecting the `loginState` flow to trigger `getActualKey` on each emitted value, but `getActualKey` triggers an emission on the `loginState` flow... I'm not sure what your goal is here

Comment: my goal is to just get request token from an endpoint by sending the apiKey as a body. it's the code i wrote while following an online course live. i was taught this topic a week ago and seems kinda strange to me.

Comment: sorry for bad formulation, as i don't know the topic very well, but i used repository class and did a simple return function as you sad @Joffrey so it works now! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't figured out what you up to

if you want to simply get last emitted value from another flow without using `collect` you can use `MutableStateFlow`  that always contains latest value in it without suspention

but if you want to combine two (or more) flows into one flow
you can use `combine` function, it passes latest emitted values to your provided lambda (`transform`), so you can transform them to one flow

here is a sample

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.combine
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flowOf

fun main() {
    val a = flowOf(1, 2, 3)
    val b = flowOf("a", "b", "c")
    val combinedFlow: Flow<Pair<Int, String>> =combine(a, b) { latestOfA, latestOfB ->
        latestOfA to latestOfB
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! i found out that i dont need two different flows. only one was enough. the problem was that i couldnot think of one simple return function. cheers!